# Cannot comment on closed posts from Android app

Tags: bug, comments, closed-questions, android-app

For some reason the Android app will does not expose a comment box at all on closed posts either for the question or any answer posts.

Especially as a moderator this is a cause of some frustration as post closures are something that I often comment on to help people learn the ropes and to do this I have to frequently switch over to a browser.

Comment: You sure it's just closed and not locked? Can you please link to one of those questions? As for being moderator it's not relevant, e.g. 10k users can't see deleted posts using the app. It's not meant for moderation.

Comment: @Shadow. Yes I'm sure. Any closed question will do, this has actually been a long standing annoyance and others have observed this too, I just finally got around to complaining.

Comment: Indeed, this was asked before. Found the dupe, voted to close.

Comment: @Shadow Next post: ineffective duplicate matching / search from mobile! I was surprised I couldn't find this already reported. In the mean time please note that when commenting on issues in software you don't even use a little less skepticism might be in order.